# Shechita for chicken

Tags: halacha, history, sources-mekorot, slaughter-shochet-shecht

What is the halachic source requiring us to ritually slaughter chicken specifically, and was there ever a time in history that Halachic Jews ate chicken without first performing ritual slaughter?

Comment: do you mean specifically chicken or all fowl? Birds, as korbanot, required a different method http://www.steinsaltz.org/Melikah1.php

Comment: Atara, thank you for bringing your question to Mi Yodeya, and welcome! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: See here the Rambam with the Gur Aryeh  http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=17036&rid=4977

Answer (score 6):

There is a documented opinion among Tannaim that there is no biblical requirement for Shechita on fowl (eg. [Chullin 27b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=27b&format=pdf) - [28a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=28&format=pdf)). Accordingly it would seem likely that some time existed before the rabbinic requirement of Shechita on fowl was enacted when Halachic Jews ate fowl without Shechita. I note that we do not rule like this opinion, but rather that Shechita on fowl is a biblical requirement.

As with all the biblical laws of Shechita, the source is oral tradition from God via Moses, as it says regarding Shechita in the Torah ([Deut 12:21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0512.htm#21)):

> וזבחת... כאשר צויתיך
>   And you shall slaughter it... as I commanded you

and there is no written record of that command.